# Configure Lotus Notes to parse utf8 in the header

Tags: email, lotus-notes, codepages, messagebroker

The question is related to a question I've previously asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158412/message-broker-sending-email
The problem is as following: I send an email vie Message Broker email node, and the Lotus Notes client displays the body of an email correctly, but the subject line is garbled; it seems it cannot parse the subject, and shows it as following: =?UTF8?Q?Application_=E2=84=96_TESTIROVANE._Approval?= 
The message and the subject line are both displayed correctly in other clients, e. g. Gmail web-client.
What should I do to make the Lotus Client parse the header and display it normally? Should I somehow configure the client itself or configure the Email node?

Comment: this is not a Notes programming question, so it does not belong on Stack Overflow.  It would be more suitable for Server Fault. In any case, there is either a bug in the Notes Client, or a problem with your actual encoding of the subject line. It's not something you can configure. Notes does understand utf8 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it was not a programming question actually

Just in case someone else runs accross the same problem with message headers: 
we didn't manage to somehow changed Lotus Configuration, so we ended up writing a Java class handling all this email stuff, specifying utf-8 for both header and message, and it works now, at least with Lotus and free smtp-servers/web-clients

Comment: How did you specified the header and message for utf-8? I am facing same issue while sending mail from java to lotus notes

Comment: @nanosoft

 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
 message.setSubject(messageSubject, "UTF-8");  
 message.setContent(emailBody, "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\""); 
 message.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8BIT");